# Ubuntu 14.04 brightness shortcut not working

Tags: 14.04, brightness, intel

I'm using Asus A450L:
Here are some info:

```
cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=d1cccc17-9e70-4682-bb40-c3df0db22e36 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

```
lspci -k | grep -A3 VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 13fd
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
```

```
for i in /sys/class/backlight/*; do echo $i; cat $i/brightness; cat $i/actual_brightness; cat $i/max_brightness; done

/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0
100
100
100
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1
18
18
100
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
103
103
937
```

I have tried these solutions and none works:

1. Create a file in ***/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf***

   ```
   Section "Device"
      Identifier  "card0"
      Driver      "intel"
      Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
      BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
2. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` in ***/etc/default/grub***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a solution for this.

But i found a workaround that might include installing a package.

It's a brightness app inspired from original Gnome brightness applet.
Here's more info: http://ubuntuguide.net/add-brightness-control-to-unity-panel

### Installing

In terminal run these:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

If the indicator doesn't start on your top bar, you can initiate it from dashboard

### Add Keyboard Shortcut

Since function key <kbd>fn</kbd> + [whatever up/down for brightness] is not working.

We have to make our own shortcut.

Go to:
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts
[image: Keyboard Shortcut Utilities]

Here, to add use +

Brightness-Up command: `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --up`

Brightness-Down command: `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --down`

**Click** the "Disabled" to assign shortcut key

Done. Until the fix comes.